# Thread-safety issues with concurrent message deserialization using BlockingCollection in C#

Tags: c#, producer-consumer, system.text.json, blockingcollection

I have the following setup

```
 internal class Program
 {
     public BlockingCollection<ArraySegment<byte>> MessageQueue { get; set; } = [];

     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         // Task.Run(Consumer)
         // Callback Func for socket ReceiveAsync calls Producer
     }

     public void Producer(ArraySegment<byte> person)
     {
         MessageQueue.Add(person);
     }

     public void Consumer(CancellationToken token)
     {
         do
         {
             var person = MessageQueue.Take();
             var update = Deserialize(person);

             if (update != null)
             {
                 DoWork(update);
             }

         } while (!token.IsCancellationRequested);
     }

     public static Person? Deserialize(ArraySegment<byte> socketMessage)
     {
         try
         {
             Person? person = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(socketMessage);

             return person;
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(e);

             return null;
         }
     }
 }
```

Now and Deserializer throws:

`System.Text.Json.JsonException: '5' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 656.  ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '5' is invalid after a single JSON value. Expected end of data.`

The error message is sort of irrelevant, if I look at Encoding.UTF8.GetString(socketMessage); the result string is corrupted, bytes are cut or added, resulting in invalid json.

What is interesting is that if I move the Deserialization in the Producer, change the BlockingCollection to `BlockingCollection<Person>` then the .Take the already deserialized object,rest of the `DoWork` works fine. It feels like on every take the .Deserialize bytes are overridden with part of the other message but I have no proof yet. What I do know is that shifting Deserializer to Producer for now works but is not ideal.

System.Text.Json should be thread safe and I am unable to reproduce the problem (yet) in isolated environment by generating random bytes. Any ideas?

Socket:

```
  var rentedBuffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(receiveBufferSize);
  var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(rentedBuffer, 0, receiveBufferSize);

  result = await handler.ReceiveAsync(buffer, cancellationToken);
  var message = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, result.Count);
  onMessage.ForEach(onmessage => onmessage(message));
  ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(rentedBuffer);
```

Comment: Are all [`ArraySegment<byte>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.arraysegment-1)s share the same mutable underlying `byte` array by any chance?

Comment: Yes,  ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(receiveBufferSize); However after received,  ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(rentedBuffer);

Comment: Good catch, so it does seem like the problem is on the socket side. If I do copy aka  .ToArray() instead of rent, the problem seems to go away, would be interesting to understand more, why this leads to such problem. And why then deserialization succeeds at producer. Added code from socket.

Comment: So what happens is, I add to the queue byte[] and if its not processed until next message arrives, it can lead to mutated byte[] even if I return the buffer?

Comment: I don't see any [message framing](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) in your code.

Comment: That's true @Stephen, if frame is larger than buffer this could potentially lead to similar issue. If you have seen some reasonable memory efficient examples of handling frames in opensource space, I would gladly take a look.

Comment: Just wanted to say that you have really cool write up in your blog about this. I wonder if nowadays with socketResult.EndOfMessage & Rents we can implement it in a shorter manner but similarly efficient. Have to give it a try.

Comment: @ans: Here you go: https://github.com/StephenClearyExamples/TcpChat https://github.com/StephenClearyExamples/TcpEcho https://github.com/davidfowl/TcpEcho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `Return` the arrays to the `ArrayPool<byte>` only after the associated `ArraySegment<byte>`s have been fully processed. Otherwise you'll have multiple `ArraySegment<byte>`s stepping on each other's toes.

Inside the `Consumer` method, at the end of the `do` loop:

```
ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(person.Array);
```

Comment: Indeed, this makes sense now. This is kind of latent error and have to be careful with mutable byte[]. I would even say that this should be placed inside the deserializer, since it allocates memory, it might as well release the byte[] for GC at finally().